# Число сказуемого

Tags: число, согласование

В мероприятии приняли/приняла участие координатор Наталья, директор М. В. Пупков, завуч...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Множественное число. Единственное число подошло бы только в случае осмысленного выделения первого персонажа, тогда остальные упоминались бы "вдогонку" (... Наталья, а также...). Если перечисление длинное (здесь имеет место "удлинение" и наименованиями должностей), полезно оформить фразу с двоеточием после слова "участие" - если это не противоречит неформальному стилю остального текста.

Comment: Вот по поводу двоеточия можно подробнее? Читала, что этот вариант возможен, но не очень поняла варианты применения. В каком случае это возможно, а в каком нет?

Comment: Это вопрос только стиля (оба варианта грамматически верны). В случае литературного текста лучше обойтись без двоеточия, поскольку при перечислении оно придаёт тексту формальный оттенок (при чтении появляется пауза, обозначающая начало перечисления). Если это официальный отчёт или газетный репортаж, то такой оттенок уместен, а обозначение двоеточием облегчает чтение, готовя к восприятию списка, который может оказаться длинным.

Comment: Спасибо. Все понятно